# change ckeditor toolbar from attribute in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am using the ckeditor with the jquery adapter plugin and im wondering how I can simplify my process and select a different toolbar dynamically from an attribute within a textarea tag.

```
<textarea class="form-control ckeditor" data-toolbar="web"></textarea>

<script>
  $('textarea.ckeditor').ckeditor({
  height : '100px',
  width : '100%',
  toolbar : $(this).attr('data-toolbar'),
  allowedContent : true 
  });
</script>
```

In this case i have a toolbar called "web" and its configured in the config file and I figure it would nicer code if I had control over the toolbars by using a data- attribute. this way i Can have different toolbars on multiple editors on my page.

Any ideas on how I can do this via the extra attribute without having to write additional code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the toolbar configuration for each editor instance by handling the [instanceCreated](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-instanceCreated) event. The new editor instance will be passed in the event data which will give you access to the `textarea` element that the editor instance is attached to and allow you to use the value of your `data-toolbar` attribute for the toolbar configuration.

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(evt) {
       evt.editor.config.toolbar = evt.editor.element.$.getAttribute('data-toolbar');
    });
</script>
```